# Why does character range class [A-z] match underscore?

Tags: regex

Tried this in many languages with same result.

JavaScript example:

```
/[A-z]/.test("_"); // => true
/[A-z]/.test("0"); // => false
/[A-z]/.test("-"); // => false
/[A-z]/.test("A"); // => true
```

Why is the first case not returing `false`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Character ranges are not that intelligent. They are based on ascii codes. Check out [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/). There exist special characters between upper-case `A-Z` and lower-case `a-z` range, namely:

```
[
\
]
^
_
`
```

So, instead of `A-z` it should be `A-Za-z`.

Comment: +1 good to document the chars between alpha sets. A handy reference.